# on click 'td' show input and when click to others 'td' restore its previous content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my snippet, so what's going on below is, when click on any td then save its text to the variable named 'lttext' for later content restore and replace its content with a input that has a name equal to the 'th' text that has the same index to the currently click td and when click to other then restore the previously clicked td's previous content and to the current click td, clear the content and please an input and so to the others but seems unfortunately not working (check my snippet). Any ideas, clues, suggestions (to make it better)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lttext;
  $(document).on("click", "#uiu_table td:not(.ghost)", function() {

    $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable").html("").text(lttext);

    $(this).addClass("editable");
    lttext = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("").html('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + $(this).closest("table").find('th:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').text().toLowerCase().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_") + '" value="' + lttext + '"/>');

    $(this).find("input").focus();
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="extend clear table table-hover" id="uiu_table">
  <thead>
    <th class="text_align_left ghost">ID</th>
    <th class="text_align_center">FIRSTNAME</th>
    <th class="text_align_center">LASTNAME</th>
    <th class="text_align_center">EMAIL</th>
    <th class="text_align_center">MOBILE</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td class="text_align_left ghost">1</td>
    <td class="text_align_center">Jano</td>
    <td class="text_align_center">Gibis</td>
    <td class="text_align_center">jano.gibis@yahee.com</td>
    <td class="text_align_center">+6392023473</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

NOTE: this is like a live table editing.

Comment: Why calling same function twice `text("").html(`, `text().toLowerCase().toLowerCase()`

Comment: `".editable"` element not appear at `html` ?

Comment: @Tushar: thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @guest271314: of course.